# What's the most basic most common Apache configuration for Django + virtualenv + WSGI?

Tags: django, apache

Since I'm trying to be pythonic in every way I'm really embracing the principle of: There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

When I'm looking at how to setup WSGI for Django & virtualenv, that's exactly not what comes to my mind. I've seen many people suggesting different solutions. I just don't understand the pros and cons let alone why there are multiple possibilites in the first place. Most of the time I've seen people fiddling with their wsgi.py files. While this seems most common it just doesn't make any sense to me. I mean - doesn't this tie my project to this concrete environment/virtualenv?

What are your solutions? Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I could come up with puts all the configuration on the webserver side (no fiddling with wsgi.py).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server
    ServerAdmin admin@server

    WSGIScriptAlias / /my/projects/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/my/projects/project:/my/virtualenvs/env
WSGIProcessGroup project

    Alias /static /my/projects/project/static
</VirtualHost>
```